# Return current date + 7 days in timestamp form

Tags: php

So I have the below property where I'm passing in a `time()-86000` value, but what would be the best call to generate a timestamp from the time the class method executes and then adds 7 days to that.

Here is what I got:

```
$profile->set_picture_expiration(time()-86000)
```

Would using `time()-86000` be the right call? I'd like to write it to the DB in timestamp format from the current time + 7 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you need +7 days, why are you using minus?

Next, 7 days are `7*24*60*60 = 604800 seconds`, not `86000`.

Finally, the easiest way to get the timestamp for such relative dates is using the `strtotime` function. In your specific case it would be `strtotime('+7 days')`.

```php
$profile->set_picture_expiration(strtotime('+7 days'));
```